# How compressibility factor is introduced in Clapeyron equation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I'm reading section *Experiment 13 Vapor Pressure of Pure Liquid* in *Experiments in Physical Chemistry* [1, p. 200]:

> For the case of vapor–liquid equilibria in the range of vapor pressures less than $\pu{1 atm},$ one may assume that the molar volume of the liquid $\widetilde{V}_\mathrm{l}$ is negligible in comparison
> with that of the gas $\widetilde{V}_\mathrm{g}$, so that $\Delta\widetilde{V} = \widetilde{V}_\mathrm{g}.$ This assumption is very good in the low-pressure region, since $\widetilde{V}_\mathrm{l}$ is usually only a few tenths of a percent of $\widetilde{V}_\mathrm{g}$. Thus we obtain
>
> $$\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dT} = \frac{\Delta_\mathrm{v}\widetilde{H}}{T\widetilde{V}_\mathrm{g}}\label{eqn:4}\tag{4}$$
>
> Since $\mathrm d\ln p = \mathrm dp/p$ and $\mathrm d(1/T) = -\mathrm dT/T^2,$ we can rewrite Eq. \eqref{eqn:4} in the form
>
> $$\frac{\mathrm d\ln p}{\mathrm d(1/T)} = -\frac{\Delta_\mathrm{v}\widetilde{H}}{R}\frac{RT}{p\widetilde{V}_\mathrm{g}} = -\frac{\Delta_\mathrm{v}\widetilde{H}}{RZ}\label{eqn:5}\tag{5}$$
>
> where we have introduced the *compressibility factor* $Z$ for the vapor:
>
> $$Z = \frac{p\widetilde{V}_\mathrm{g}}{RT}\label{eqn:6}\tag{6}$$
>
> Equation \eqref{eqn:5} is a convenient form of the Clapeyron equation. We can see that, *if* the vapor were a perfect gas $(Z \equiv 1)$ and $\Delta_\mathrm{v}\widetilde{H}$ were independent of temperature, then a plot of $\ln p$ versus $1/T$ would be a straight line, the slope of which would determine $\Delta_\mathrm{v}\widetilde{H}.$ Indeed, for
> many liquids, $\ln p$ is almost a linear function of $1/T,$ which implies at least that $\Delta_\mathrm{v}\widetilde{H}/Z$ is almost constant.

How is it possible to rewrite equation \eqref{eqn:4} into equation \eqref{eqn:5} in order to introduce the compressibility factor?

#### Reference

1. Garland, C. W.; Nibler, J. W.; Shoemaker, D. P. *Experiments in Physical Chemistry*, 8th ed.; McGraw-Hill Higher Education: Boston, **2009**. ISBN 978-0-07-282842-9.

Comment: @Edgardo In the future, please cite your sources, avoid posting screenshots of text, and please try to formulate the question as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The quoted transformation is an application of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d} (\ln p)}{\mathrm{d} (1/T)} &= \frac{\mathrm{d} (\ln p)}{\mathrm{d}p} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d} (1/T)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}T} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{\mathrm{d} (\ln p)}{\mathrm{d}p} \cdot \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}(1/T)}{\mathrm{d}T}\right)^{-1} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}T} \\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{p} \cdot (-T^2) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}T}
\end{align}$$

Substituting in the expression for $\mathrm{d}p/\mathrm{d}T$ will yield the desired equation.

If you're not comfortable with the chain rule (i.e. $\mathrm{d}z/\mathrm{d}y = (\mathrm{d}z/\mathrm{d}x)(\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}y)$), or with the fact that $(\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}y)^{-1} = \mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x$, I'd suggest picking up a book on calculus, which will explain these things.

Note that, although this *looks* as though we are treating derivatives as fractions and 'cancelling out top and bottom', this is not the correct approach and will fail in other cases. Again, I refer you to a calculus book for a discussion of this.